# vlookup for multiple files using python

Tags: python, vlookup

I'm trying to perform automatic vlookup for multiple files using python.
All target file names end with ~0.txt.
I want to match 'location' information in 'list80.csv' to 'loc' information in the individual target file and input 'gt' value for each 'location'.

[image]

Running the code produce only one result file and error code such as:

[image]

Please let me know if you have solutions.

Comment: please post code instead of pictures next time

Comment: looking at the error, are you sure `loc` in the files has unique values?

Comment: some `loc` might have two values.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it again and come back later

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.